# How To Restart Sudo Service in Ubuntu 18+

Tags: 18.04, sudo

From "[Do we need to reboot after adding an user to sudoers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/665950/)", it is apparent that restarting Sudo Service is necessary, or reboot. However the recommended way, which works for Ubuntu 14.04, is no longer working for Ubuntu 18+:

```
$ sudo service sudo restart
Failed to restart sudo.service: Unit sudo.service is masked.
```

Solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`masked` services are when the systemd unit files are linked to `/dev/null`/ You can see the `sudo.service`

```
$ systemctl status sudo.service
● sudo.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)

$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Jan 18  2018 /lib/systemd/system/sudo.service -> /dev/null
```

Some services are used within systemd, and not actual daemons with processes that run in the background. For example, you cannot start/stop `halt.service`. But if you place your scripts in `/usr/lib/systemd/system-shutdown/`, they will be run before the system is halted or rebooted.

### Sudo Usage

You don't need to reboot to use sudo. Simply add [users and your settings to the Sudoers file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I don't quite understand most of it except for the conclusion _"You don't need to reboot to use sudo"_. It might be true for adding users, but from the quoted question, and for my case, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164220/, not restarting Sudo Service doesn't have any effect.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that `sudo.service` is not a "real" service. There isn't any sudo process or daemon running in the background, and you need to restart it to pick up changes to the sudoers file. Ah, I see what you are getting. The other question is clearer on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I wanted to give my two cents to newbs like me. I also thought the change wasn't working, it was just silly of me that I thought you didn't need to type `sudo` anymore after the first one for however long timeout in `sudoers` is set for (default 15 min). In other words you have to keep typing `sudo` before any relevant command, it just doesn't ask you for password anymore.